# Эквивалент кода PHP на Python

Tags: php, python

Мне нужно сделать объявление функции на пайтоне, так, как на PHP:

```
<?php
$code = function(){ echo "lol";};
$code();
```

То есть вот так:

```
$code = function(){ echo "lol";};
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945467/python-store-function-in-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946256/12593651)

Answer (score 1):

Сама функция:

```
def say():
    print('lol')
```

Вывод функции:

```
say()
```

Вот и всё